# css div height set to a dynamic size

Tags: css

Is it possible to work only on css, to set a dynamic height of the div to a proportion of full screen?

Would like to have something like the following example

```
.my_div {
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
}
```

Comment: It is ok to use % based dimensions

Comment: Yes. http://jsfiddle.net/3mzBX/

Comment: I should have clarified my question, does the % based setting work as a proportion of full screen?

Comment: @ydoow Depends. It is based on the height of the parent element, unless it is `position: fixed;`, it which case isn't depended on the viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

No, only dynamic width. You need javascript to adjust height dynamically.

Unless you are looking to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951875/dynamic-height-of-div-with-css), in which case search before asking next time. :)

Comment: True. Mistook question as a wrapper/body element. Post that as answer!

Comment: @ydoow: The `body` and `html` would need to have their heights set. http://jsfiddle.net/3mzBX/3/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Alexander O'Mara.The parents like html or body or any wrapper must have dynamic heights on js that their children elements are free to set their heights with percentage.It is not possible to work only on css.